# jQuery click event issues with appended list item

Tags: jquery, html

I am having some issues with a click event which im guessing is happening because what I am clicking is getting appended after the page loads here is the jquery and jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/PTHsY/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Adding a project
$('.project-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //grab the user input for the new project
    var project = $('.project-val').val();

    //Add the project to the list
    $('<li></li>').addClass(project).appendTo('.project-list');
    $('<a></a>').attr("href",project).text(project).appendTo('li.'+project);

    // create the div where the categories will go
    $('<div></div>').attr("id",project).appendTo('.category-wrapper');
    // hide the div untill it is called upon
    $('div#'+project).fadeOut(function(){
        $('<h1></h1>').text(project).css("text-align","center").appendTo('div#'+project);
        // add the input for the category div
        $('<input>').attr("type","text").addClass('category-val').appendTo('div#'+project);
        $('<input>').attr("type","submit").attr("value","Add Category").addClass("category-btn-"+project).appendTo('div#'+project);
        // add the ul
        $('<ul></ul>').attr("class","category-list").appendTo('div#'+project);
        // add the back button
        $('<p></p>').text("back").addClass('category-back').css("cursor","pointer").appendTo('div#'+project);
    });

    // clear the input search
    $('.project-val').val('');

}); 

$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    selectedDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    alert("clicked");
    $('.project-wrapper').fadeOut(function(){
        $('div#'+selectedDiv).fadeIn();
    });
});
});
```

I'm trying to show the hidden div only after I click on the added list item. For some reason which I stated my guess above it is not working. I added an alert "clicked" for when any anchor element is clicked but I get no responsose

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to assign events to dynamic elements. Add the click event to a non-dynamic ancestor of your `a` element using [jQuery's `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), passing in your `a` selector as a parameter (in this case I've used the document's `body`):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    ...
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PTHsY/1/).**

> When a `selector` is provided, the event handler is referred to as *delegated*. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Comment: Thanks what is the reason why i have to use "on" on dynamic elements?

Comment: and ill give u the check as soon as I can

Comment: @swsa because your element doesn't exist when that event handler is first initiated. Your event handler isn't assigned to anything and thus doesn't exist when your element is added dynamically. In using `on()` we're adding the event handler to the `body`, which exists before the element is added.

Comment: I don't want to be annoying but if I send you what I'm trying to do in detail which for you I'm sure is pretty simple could you help me?

Comment: @swsa I'm afraid I'm about to go to bed (it's 11PM here), sorry!